# Xcode 4 - My App Is Installed But Never Run On Device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My app builds perfectly, and gets installed onto my iPod Touch 1G (iOS 3.1.3), but when Xcode 4 says it is running it on my device, it never gets started. If I check in the Console for my device in the Organizer, I get the following:

```
Fri Jul  8 19:23:37 unknown mobile_installationd[4204] <Error>: 0080ba00 install_embedded_profile: Skipping the installation of the embedded profile
Fri Jul  8 19:23:47 unknown SpringBoard[25] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
Fri Jul  8 19:23:56 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: (0x837000) spawn_service_agent: Could not look up service in the map
Fri Jul  8 19:23:56 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: (0x837000) handle_start_service: Could not spawn the com.apple.debugserver service agent: 515048
Fri Jul  8 19:23:56 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: (0x837000) set_response_error: handle_start_service InvalidService
Fri Jul  8 19:24:06 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: (0x837000) spawn_service_agent: Could not look up service in the map
Fri Jul  8 19:24:06 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: (0x837000) handle_start_service: Could not spawn the com.apple.debugserver.applist service agent: 515048
Fri Jul  8 19:24:06 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: (0x837000) set_response_error: handle_start_service InvalidService
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this, as I cannot debug it on my device at the moment?

EDIT: Never mind. I forgot to try simply rebooting my iPod - I had restarted Xcode, and then my Mac, but did not think to reboot my iPod!

Comment: wild guess: remove existing app from device, full clean build, fresh install, try again.

Comment: Yes, 1G - the most innovative of them all. I test on it as I want to ensure compatibility with old devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I forgot to try simply rebooting my iPod - I had restarted Xcode, and then my Mac, but did not think to reboot my iPod!